# Need to write a script working under Win32 to put the tags in place for documentation automatically C++/C#

Tags: scripting, documentation-generation, code-documentation

We are managing a C++/C# library and we noticed that many classes and functions were left undocumented.

We thought about writing a script which would parse the code to look for undocumented classes and method to produce a list of undocumented classes/methods/functions.

We would like, as well, the script to put the dOxygen tags in place for documentation where there are missing. i.e. if such piece of code is found:

```
bool Myclass:undocumentedMethod(int a);
```

It would be replaced with

```
/// \brief <DESCRIPTION>
/// \param a <DESCRIPTION>
/// \return bool <DESCRIBE RETURN VALUE>
bool Myclass:undocumentedMethod(int a);
```

Of course if the function has in the future an automatically generated documentation header but nobody touched the header it would still be reported as undocumented in the report.

What scripting language would you use to develop such a tool ?

Anthony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at http://submain.com/GhostDoc/ to insert docs by a hotkey or mouse.   Development of a similar add-in could be accomplished in the same manner as GhostDoc, by starting with Studio's Add-In template project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Perl?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did not, I will give it a try.